# How do I rewrite this WordPress URL?

Tags: url-rewriting

I'm using WordPress with woocommerce and I am trying to rewrite a url, i.e

> WEBSITE/product/celebrity-aston-recliner-fabric/?attribute_pa_size=standard-recliner&attribute_pa_action=dual-motor-lift-tilt

to

> WEBSITE/product/celebrity-aston-recliner-fabric/standard-recliner/dual-motor-lift-tilt/

Can anyone help?

Managed to get wordpress to accept the url:WEBSITE/product/celebrity-aston-recliner-fabric/standard-recliner/dual-motor-lift-tilt/ with this:
function custom_rewrite( $wp_rewrite ) {

```
$feed_rules = array(
    'product/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)'    =>  'index.php?product='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1).'&attribute_pa_size='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2).'&attribute_pa_action='. $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3)
);

$wp_rewrite->rules = $feed_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
```

}
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite' );

However the first URL still exists and the new URL doesn't set the variataion

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule will help

Comment: you can also use `permalinks` under `settings` tags inside admin panel

Comment: I have looked at these and cannot get my head around it also permalinks don't have and option for this :(, Thanks for your guys help though i'll keep looking

Comment: playaround with `htaccess` you'll definitely get a work-around. {https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules} will help

Comment: Still no look i have tried many things such as RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)attribute_pa_size=standard-recliner($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)attribute_pa_action=dual-motor-lift-tilt($|&)
RewriteRule ^celebrityrecliner\.co\.uk/product/celebrity-hertford-recliner-fabric/$ /celebrityrecliner.co.uk/product/celebrity-hertford-recliner-fabric/standard-recliner/dual-motor-lift-tilt/?&%{QUERY_STRING} and nothing happens, can you advice? Also i do appreciate the help this has been bugging me